# Android - Java - MediaStore - How to use selection for multiple conditions

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver, mediastore

I wan't to get all the document (Docs) files from an android device. I use ContentResolver with MediaStore.Files to achive that. I can get all the files from one type , for example: pdf , but I wonder how to get files from number of types.

My code:

```
    String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" +
            "";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf")};

    ArrayList<MyFile> list  = new ArrayList<MyFile>();

    Uri contentUri  = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");


    String[] columns = {
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE ,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE ,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA ,
    };
    String SortOrder = null;


    Cursor cursor = contentR.query(contentUri ,
            columns ,
            selection ,
            selectionArgs ,
            SortOrder);
```

How can I use the selection & selectioArgs for multiple conditions like in SQL: OR , AND ...
The selectionArgs will have all the files types that I'm looking for: pdf , txt , doc ...

For example:
Selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + "OR" + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" ;

SelectionArgs = {"pdf" , "txt"};

Thanks for any help or direction :-)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add more selectionArgs, each for every file type. Or you just create an list or array which contains all the file types as strings. Next you only need a loop which goes to the next file type until there are no more left.
For example:

```
ArrayList<MyFile> list  = new ArrayList<MyFile>();
ArrayList<String> fileTypeArray = new ArrayList<DString>(); 

for(int i = 0; i < fileTypeArray.size(); i++){
     String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + "";
     String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {     MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileTypeArray.get(i))};

    Uri contentUri  = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
    String[] columns = {
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE ,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE ,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA ,
    };
    String SortOrder = null;

     Cursor cursor = contentR.query(contentUri ,
            columns ,
            selection ,
            selectionArgs ,
            SortOrder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to not include the MIME_TYPE in the selection but having it in the columns allows you to check it when processing each entry in the cursor.

Something like:

```
val projection - arrayOf(
    MediaStore.Downloads.MIME_TYPE,
...

if (cursor.count > 0) {
        val mimeColumn : Int =
            cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE)
        cursor.use { cursor ->
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            do {
                val mimeType = cursor.getString(mimeColumn)
                ...
                if( mimeType == MediaStore.Downloads.MIME_TYPE ) { // or wherever...
                    // process it
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext())
        }
        ...
```